# Angular ng-content in Storybook stories not working

Tags: angular, storybook

Given the following component inside `anchor.component.ts`:

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'lib-anchor',
  templateUrl: './anchor.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./anchor.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule,
  ],
  template: `
    <a [href]="link">
      <ng-content></ng-content>
    </a>
  `
})
export class LibAnchorComponent {
  @Input() link?: string;
}
```

And the following within `anchor.component.stories.ts`:

```
import { LibAnchorComponent } from './anchor.component';

export default {
  component: LibAnchorComponent,
};

export const Primary = {
  args: {
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  render: (args: any) => `<lib-anchor>hello world</lib-anchor>`
};
```

I thought that I would see "hello world" as the template and "https://google.com" as the `href` attribute value, but I see neither. This is what is rendered as the `Primary` story:

[image: image of rendered html]

I have tried both the CSF 2.0 and CSF 3.0 way of doing things but neither have worked for me. The code posted here is based on https://storybook.js.org/blog/component-story-format-3-0/.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct answer eventually. Turns out you have to return an object from the `render` method instead of a string:

```
export const Primary: StoryObj<LibAnchorComponent> = {
  args: {
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  render: (args: any) => ({    
    template: `<lib-anchor link="${args.link}">hello world ${args.link}</lib-anchor>`
  })
};
```

This will correctly render both the given `link` and the projected content.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    import { Story, Meta } from "@storybook/angular/types-6-0";
    import { moduleMetadata } from "@storybook/angular";
    import { CommonModule } from "@angular/common";
    import { LibAnchorComponent } from ".../libAnchor";
  

    export default {
      title: "Librery/Anchor",
      component: LibAnchorComponent,
      decorators: [
        moduleMetadata({
          declarations: [],
          imports: [CommonModule],
        }),
      ],
    } as Meta;
    
    const Template: Story<LibAnchorComponent> 
= (args: LibAnchorComponent ) => ({
      component: LibAnchorComponent ,
      props: args,
    });
    
     
    
    export const AnchorExample= Template.bind({});
    
    AnchorExample.args = {
    //example
    };
```

Comment: Due to different formatting it is very hard to see what actually has been changed

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this issue occurs when using the `render` function. In my Storybook Angular project, I am using the `template` option instead, then everything seems to work fine for me:

```js
export const Primary = {
  args: {
    link: 'https://google.com'
  },
  template: `<lib-anchor>hello world</lib-anchor>`
};
```